# Persisting the state of d3 treemap on drilling down to child nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am working on the d3 treemap v5 in which I need to persist the state of the treemap in localstorage on each user click. My code is in https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-treemap-wfbtg
When a user clicks the top parent tile it is drilled down to the children tiles. How to persist that in local storage when the user reloads the browser he wants to see the drilled down children tiles.

```
class Treegraph extends React.Component {
  createTreeChart = () => {
    const width = 550;
    const height = 500;
    var paddingAllowance = 2;
    const format = d3.format(",d");
    const checkLowVal = d => {
      console.log("ChecklowVal", d);
      if (d.value < 2) {
        return true;
      }
    };
    const name = d =>
      d
        .ancestors()
        .reverse()
        .map(d => d.data.name)
        .join(" / ");
    function tile(node, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
      d3.treemapBinary(node, 0, 0, width, height);
      for (const child of node.children) {
        child.x0 = x0 + (child.x0 / width) * (x1 - x0);
        child.x1 = x0 + (child.x1 / width) * (x1 - x0);
        child.y0 = y0 + (child.y0 / height) * (y1 - y0);
        child.y1 = y0 + (child.y1 / height) * (y1 - y0);
      }
    }
    const treemap = data =>
      d3.treemap().tile(tile)(
        d3
          .hierarchy(data)
          .sum(d => d.value)
          .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
      );
    const svg = d3
      .select("#chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
      .style("font", "16px sans-serif");

    const x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]);

    let group = svg.append("g").call(render, treemap(data));

    function render(group, root) {
      const node = group
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(root.children.concat(root))
        .join("g");

      node
        .filter(d => (d === root ? d.parent : d.children))
        .attr("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("click", d => (d === root ? zoomout(root) : zoomin(d)));

      var tool = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "toolTip");

      d3.select(window.frameElement).style("height", height - 20 + "px");
      d3.select(window.frameElement).style("width", width - 20 + "px");
      node
        .append("rect")
        .attr("id", d => (d.leafUid = "leaf"))
        .attr("fill", d =>
          d === root ? "#fff" : d.children ? "#045c79" : "#045c79"
        )
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .on("mousemove", function(d) {
          tool.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px");
          tool.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 20 + "px");
          tool.style("display", "inline-block");
          tool.html(`${d.data.name}<br />(${format(d.data.value)})`);
        })
        .on("click", function(d) {
          tool.style("display", "none");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tool.style("display", "none");
        });
      node
        .append("foreignObject")
        .attr("class", "foreignObject")
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return d.dx - paddingAllowance;
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return d.dy - paddingAllowance;
        })
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .attr("class", "labelbody")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
      node
        .append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", d => (d.clipUid = "clip"))
        .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", d => d.leafUid.href);

      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", d => d.clipUid)
        .attr("font-weight", d => (d === root ? "bold" : null))
        .attr("font-size", d => {
          if (d === root) return "0.8em";
          const width = x(d.x1) - x(d.x0),
            height = y(d.y1) - y(d.y0);
          return Math.max(
            Math.min(
              width / 5,
              height / 2,
              Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height) / 25
            ),
            9
          );
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", d => (d === root ? null : "middle"))
        .attr("transform", d =>
          d === root
            ? null
            : `translate(${(x(d.x1) - x(d.x0)) / 2}, ${(y(d.y1) - y(d.y0)) /
                2})`
        )
        .selectAll("tspan")
        .data(d =>
          d === root
            ? name(d).split(/(?=\/)/g)
            : checkLowVal(d)
            ? d.data.name.split(/(\s+)/).concat(format(d.data.value))
            : d.data.name.split(/(\s+)/).concat(format(d.data.value))
        )
        .join("tspan")
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr(
          "y",
          (d, i, nodes) =>
            `${(i === nodes.length - 1) * 0.3 + (i - nodes.length / 2) * 0.9}em`
        )
        .text(d => d);
      node
        .selectAll("text")
        .classed("text-title", d => d === root)
        .classed("text-tile", d => d !== root)
        .filter(d => d === root)
        .selectAll("tspan")
        .attr("y", "1.1em")
        .attr("x", undefined);
      group.call(position, root);
    }
    function position(group, root) {
      group
        .selectAll("g")
        .attr("transform", d =>
          d === root ? `translate(0,-30)` : `translate(${x(d.x0)},${y(d.y0)})`
        )
        .select("rect")
        .attr("width", d => (d === root ? width : x(d.x1) - x(d.x0)))
        .attr("height", d => (d === root ? 30 : y(d.y1) - y(d.y0)));
    }

    // When zooming in, draw the new nodes on top, and fade them in.
    function zoomin(d) {
      console.log("The zoomin func", d.data);
      x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
      y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);
      const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
      const group1 = (group = svg.append("g").call(render, d));
      svg
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(t =>
          group0
            .transition(t)
            .remove()
            .call(position, d.parent)
        )
        .call(t =>
          group1
            .transition(t)
            .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(0, 1))
            .call(position, d)
        );
    }

    // When zooming out, draw the old nodes on top, and fade them out.
    function zoomout(d) {
      console.log("The zoomout func", d.parent.data);
      x.domain([d.parent.x0, d.parent.x1]);
      y.domain([d.parent.y0, d.parent.y1]);
      const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
      const group1 = (group = svg.insert("g", "*").call(render, d.parent));
      svg
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(t =>
          group0
            .transition(t)
            .remove()
            .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(1, 0))
            .call(position, d)
        )
        .call(t => group1.transition(t).call(position, d.parent));
    }

    return svg.node();
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createTreeChart();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div id="chart" />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think storing a path as array of node names would be a simple solution. When you created the tree you can check to local storage, then you can zoom in programmatically and recursively comparing the name of child nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick idea, store the name as ID on local storage. Hopefully name is unique, otherwise make sure you have an unique ID for each node.

https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-treemap-4ehbf?file=/src/treegraph.js

- first load localstorage for `lastSelection` with last selected node name

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    const lastSelection = localStorage.getItem("lastSelection");
    console.log("lastSelection:", lastSelection);
    this.createTreeChart(lastSelection);
  }
```

- add a parameter to you `createTreeChart` so when it loads and there is a lastaSelection you have to reload that state

```js
  createTreeChart = (lastSelection = null) => {
```

- decouple your treemap in a variable, filter the `lastSelection` node and zoomin into it. this step could be improved, not sure if the refreshing zoomin is interesting.

```js
    const tree = treemap(data);
    let group = svg.append("g").call(render, tree);
    if (lastSelection !== null) {
      const lastNode = tree
        .descendants()
        .find(e => e.data.name === lastSelection);
      zoomin(lastNode);
    }
```

- finally update localStorage on node click.

```js
      node
        .filter(d => (d === root ? d.parent : d.children))
        .attr("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("click", d => {
          if (d === root) {
           localStorage.setItem("lastSelection", null);
            zoomout(root);
          } else {
           localStorage.setItem("lastSelection", d.data.name);
            zoomin(d);
          }
        });
```

This could be improved, but it's a starting point.